# How to change date format in R?

Tags: r, date

In my dataset I have date columns (character) where dates are in the following format `%d.%m.%Y`. I want to change the dates into this format `%Y-%m-%d`. This simple task has proven to be amazingly tricky. How would you solve this?

Comment: `as.Date("24.09.2020",format="%d.%m.%Y")`. Look at `?as.Date`, in particular the `format` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. Here, we used dummy data and the functions `format()` and `as.Date()`. Here the code:

```
#Code
df$date2 <- format(as.Date(df$date,'%d.%m.%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Output:

```
         date      date2
1  01.01.2020 2020-01-01
2  02.01.2020 2020-01-02
3  03.01.2020 2020-01-03
4  04.01.2020 2020-01-04
5  05.01.2020 2020-01-05
6  06.01.2020 2020-01-06
7  07.01.2020 2020-01-07
8  08.01.2020 2020-01-08
9  09.01.2020 2020-01-09
10 10.01.2020 2020-01-10
11 11.01.2020 2020-01-11
12 12.01.2020 2020-01-12
13 13.01.2020 2020-01-13
14 14.01.2020 2020-01-14
15 15.01.2020 2020-01-15
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(date = structure(1:15, .Label = c("01.01.2020", 
"02.01.2020", "03.01.2020", "04.01.2020", "05.01.2020", "06.01.2020", 
"07.01.2020", "08.01.2020", "09.01.2020", "10.01.2020", "11.01.2020", 
"12.01.2020", "13.01.2020", "14.01.2020", "15.01.2020"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you. I got my problem solved with this lubridate function -> mydata$columnname <- dmy(mydata$columnname)

Comment: @erinho Yeah it is also possible use what you mention. Smart move !

Answer (score 0):

If your "dates" look like this then they are strings, not dates, and you can rapidly change the format with string manipulation, as in

```R
f <- function(s) gsub("([^.]+)[.]([^.]+)+[.]([^.]+)", "\\3-\\2-\\1", s)
```

Here is an example of its application:

```R
X <- data.frame(date = "12.3.2020")
X$newdate <- with(X, f(date))
```

Printing `X` produces

> ```
>        date   newdate
> 1 12.3.2020 2020-3-12
> ```

This method is preferable if you want to maintain these dates as character fields, because it avoids the (relatively large) computational expense of conversion into date types.  This use of regular expressions in `gsub` illustrates the kind of things one often goes through in cleaning and preprocessing data and has (obvious) value beyond just reformatting dates.

Comment: Thank you. I got my problem solved with this lubridate function -> mydata$columnname <- dmy(mydata$columnname)